# Difference between key credentials and password credentials for Azure Service Principal?

Tags: python, azure, service-principal

I'm programmatically creating Azure application and service principal registrations using Python and have been asked to provide a client secret for the apps as well.

In the [ServicePrincipalsUpdateParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.serviceprincipalupdateparameters?view=azure-python) class, it looks like I have the option to update [password_credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.passwordcredential?view=azure-python) and [key_credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.keycredential?view=azure-python). Can anyone explain the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PasswordCredentials` are for, well, passwords. They are text strings.

The `KeyCredentials` are for authenticating with a certificate. To be precise, the key credential contains the cert's *public key*, corresponding to this pane in the Azure Portal (AAD -> App registrations -> Certificates & secrets):

[image]

Comment: Correct, password credentials are also known as client secrets.